# How to combine another input if inputs already exist in listview

Tags: vb.net, listview

Can someone help me with my code. I'm inserting data that already exist in my listview but instead of adding or update the exising item in my listview, it's adding a new row with the same items.

This is how my code looks.

```
Dim itm As New ListViewItem
itm = lvwcart.Items.Add(txtquantity.Text)
itm.SubItems.Add(txtname.Text)
itm.SubItems.Add(cmbsize.Text)
itm.SubItems.Add(cmbtype.Text)
itm.SubItems.Add(txtprice.Text)
```

My Listview adding an items.

| QTY | Coffee | Size | Type | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Spanish | MEDIUM | HOT | 260 |
| 1 | Spanish | LARGE | HOT | 140 |
| 1 | Spanish | MEDIUM | ICED | 135 |
| 1 | Spanish | LARGE | ICED | 145 |
| 1 | Spanish | MEDIUM | HOT | 270 |

---

Target Output:

| QTY | Coffee | Size | Type | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Spanish | MEDIUM | HOT | 390 |
| 1 | Spanish | LARGE | HOT | 140 |
| 1 | Spanish | MEDIUM | ICED | 135 |
| 1 | Spanish | LARGE | ICED | 145 |

Instead of adding a row. the last row in my first table combine to the first row

Thank you for your help

Comment: sorry I used block for my code. I can't use the code format.

Comment: Yes, you can use the code format. If you don't know how to, spend some time in the Help Center to learn. You don't have to wait for information to come to you.

Comment: You are calling `Add` so why would you expect it to do anything other than add? If you want to modify an existing item then you have to get that existing item first and then modify it. I think that you can work out how to get an item from a `ListView`.